# How to delete duplicate rows based on cell value with AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script

I have recently written a code in AppScript which passes a certain range (1 row) in a spreadsheet to another. It adds the new row after the existing rows in the destination table.
The script I use to pass the row is--

```
function report() 
{
 var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName('X');
 var range = sheetraw.getRange('A2:P2');
 var data = range.getValues();
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AwevYEBTQYPGFTco7bnczqSGYgWEK1sU2ojLJhocTpk/edit#gid=1804330717');
 var reqsheet = ss.getSheetByName("reporting");
 reqsheet.getRange(reqsheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,16).clear();
 reqsheet.getRange(reqsheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,16).setValues(data);
}
```

I want a google appscript that can delete rows in a spreadsheet which have duplicate values in a articular column (say, column C labelled "RR/TR No."). I want it to specifically keep the bottom most/most recently added duplicate row and delete all the duplicate rows that were added before.

Example:
[image]
Here, rows 15 & 16 have duplicate RR/TR Nos., & I want row 15 (highlighted red) to be deleted while keeping row 16.

This is the row that gets passed from sheet "X", to the "reporting" sheet--
[image]

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try:**

```
const Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const Sheet = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(`X`)

function removeDuplicates() {

  const targetColumn = 3 // Column C

  const uniqueValues = Sheet.getDataRange()
                            .offset(1, 0)
                            .getValues()
                            .reverse()
                            .reduce((prev, row) => {

                              const [unique, test] = prev
                              const value = row[targetColumn-1]

                              if (value === ``) return prev

                              if (!test.includes(value)) {
                                test.push(value)
                                unique.push(row)
                              }

                              return prev

                            }, [[], []])[0]
                            .reverse()

  Sheet.getDataRange()
       .offset(1, 0)
       .clearContent()

  Sheet.getRange(2, 1, uniqueValues.length, uniqueValues[0].length)
       .setValues(uniqueValues)

}
```

Commented:

```
const Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const Sheet = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(`X`)

function removeDuplicates() {

  const targetColumn = 3 // Column C

  const uniqueValues = Sheet.getDataRange()
                            // Ignore header row.
                            .offset(1, 0)
                            .getValues()
                            // Handle the last rows first.
                            .reverse()
                            // Using an array to store filtered row, and an array to check for unique values.
                            .reduce((prev, row) => {

                              // Destructure for easy access.
                              const [unique, test] = prev
                              // The value in question.
                              const value = row[targetColumn-1]

                              // Skip if we caught a blank row.
                              if (value === ``) return prev

                              // If the current value is unique:
                              if (!test.includes(value)) {
                                // Add it to our array for testing unique values,
                                test.push(value)
                                // And to our unique rows array.
                                unique.push(row)
                              }

                              return prev

                            // [0] to access the uniqueRows array.
                            }, [[], []])[0]
                            // Reverse to put it back in order.
                            .reverse()

  Sheet.getDataRange()
       .offset(1, 0)
       .clearContent()

  Sheet.getRange(2, 1, uniqueValues.length, uniqueValues[0].length)
       .setValues(uniqueValues)

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and kindly providing a workaround!

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem of this type a few years ago and took quite a different route. I had some historic data to which I added some recent updates. As a result there were some lines which were essentially the same record, but one had old payload data and one had new payload data. I wanted to delete the records with the old payload.

> 1 - Add the new records to be end of the sheet of old records.
> 2 - Sort by the key and the update date to get the pairs of records adjacent.
> 3 - Add a formula into a new column at the far right which recognises that the record and the next one are pairs with the data to delete in the upper record. Return "Delete" if this is the case and "Keep" if not.
> 4 - Copy the formula to the end using lastRow() in a bulk copy/paste so the formula affects all records.
> 5 - Copy the column and Paste Special Values to preserve them.
> 6 - Sort the data on the last column descending.
> 7 - Starting on the first record, deleteRow() if the last column says "Delete".
> 8 - Loop while this is still "Delete" and eventually they will all go.

Does this help?